# add display and update mysql field with drop down

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I want to store a set of categories in a mysql database field. The field is varchar and the categories will be entered comma-delimited. When loaded in an add or update form, there should be a drop down multiple choice list of categories and a field to enter a new category or a set of categories comma delimited.

So the issue here is how to:

1. extract the list of categories as a column from the database
2. make the drop down display only one of each category, even though each row will have multiple categories in it, for example:

   ```
   row1: category: entertainment,news,music
   row2: category: news,religion,entertainment
   row3: category: news,music,religion
   ```

   and the displayed drop-down list should look like:

   ```
   entertainment
   news
   religion
   music
   ```
3. Allow the user to add new categories to the database, in addition to selections in the drop down list.

Probably there is a better way to do this, but since I'm not very experienced with php/mysql, I'm not sure how. I tried to add the category column to the database as type SET or type ENUM in PHPMyAdmin but no matter what I did I get an error 1064, so I gave up and decided to just use comma delimited text. I believe that I will need to use the explode and implode php functions to store this data. At the moment, there is just a text field for category, but this will not protect the user from typos that might result in extra categories from showing up due to misspellings of an existing category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I guess you are wrong on the database schema. This is a typical 1-to-n relationship so usually what you should have is something like:

[Categories Table]

- categoryId
- name
- ... (other fields)

[Content Table] (The table that contains the data to be categorized)

- contentId
- name
- ... (other fields)

And you have a table to join the two and allow multiple relationships.

[Content_Belongs_To_Category Table]

- contentId
- categoryId

So now you perform a select on the Categories table to get the list you need for the drop down, and for each category the content belongs to you add a row to the relationship table.

You could finally join [Content Table] with [Categories Table] and [Content_Belongs_To_Category Table] to get the list of categories an item belongs to (as an array, or you could use GROUP_CONCAT to get them as a comma separated string)

Probably there may be too many unknown terms on my answer but it should get you started to have it sorted out (properly :)).

Edit: Sample SQL statements

- Get all categories

SELECT * FROM Categories

- Get categories that a content belongs to

SELECT * FROM Content_Belongs_To_Category cbtc
INNER JOIN Categories c ON cbtc.categoryId = c.categoryId
WHERE cbtc.contentId =

- Get content and categories as a string

SELECT co.contentId, min(co.name) as name, group_concat(c.name) as categories
FROM Content co 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Content_Belongs_To_Category cbtc ON cbtc.contentId = co.contentId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Categories c ON cbtc.categoryId = c.categoryId
GROUP BY co.contentId

Comment: Can you help me out with some hypothetical mysql statements to create this relationship?

Comment: There you go. (Sorry if there are typos, I just wrote them, haven't tried them)

Comment: Ok, so I've created two more tables as you described. Do I need to populate the join table,"content_belongs_to_category" somehow? or does this happen in some automatic way? There is also the question of using auto_increment on the join table, do I need to do that, or some kind of index/primarykey etc?

Comment: Obviously for each category the content belongs to you need to add a row in belongs_to table. I presumed that categoryId and contentId are both primary keys on each respective table and both together form a primary key on the belongs_to table. I think you should read some database theory

Comment: Didn't you see the part of my initial post that said my experience is limited with php/mysql? I start a new job on Monday and am trying to finish up this project, so getting told to RTFM is pretty unhelpful, however, your other comments are very helpful, so I'll forgive you. Also, seems impossible and makes no sense to have both fields set as primary keys in belongs_to table.

Comment: @aplhablender, It was a friendly advice not an RTFM. If you are really interested in being good at it you should spend some time to the theory behind it. (Otherwise why would I bother write such a long answer, but to help you?) As for the primary key, it is not impossible and makes perfect sense. (Actually is the suggested way to go). If you add both fields as one primary key, you make sure no duplicates can be entered in the database and at the same time since the primary key is an index it will speed your queries up.

Comment: Thanks Mobius, sorry if I was a bit grouchy there, I appreciate your help.